# How to improve prerender speed for Twitterbot request?

Tags: twitter, timeout, prerender

For the project I am working, I've set up a prerender service on the same server as the project and use Nginx to pass social media requests to the prerender service.

I have observed that if an authorized user shares a page to the Twitter, it usually works, i.e. the meta tag image and text are rendered as a twitter card. However, if the user has shared other pages of the same project, the images are usually not rendered when the user visits his twitter posts.

From the Nginx access log, it seems Twitterbots made requests at the same time and the prerender service was too slow to render the pages. 499 status were shown in the Twitterbot requests and 504 were shown in the prerender log.

The server is hosted on the UpCloud using 1 CPU and 2 GB memory data plan. The prerender service is run in a docker container with 300MB, it will cache rendered pages for 60 seconds. Due to the memory quota, I hesitate to increase the cache duration.

I have been studying the server logs and possible solutions, but haven't been able to come up with other solution than refactoring the UI. Had anyone else struggled with this issue and how do you overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a pretty underpowered server for running a Prerender server. You might want to at least give it more RAM and possibly another CPU to get better performance. 504's shouldn't be happening often at all.

Depending on how long your pages take to prerender, caching for much longer than 60 seconds is highly recommended. You probably won't see many cache hits in 60 seconds (from users sharing URLs on twitter) for a single URL unless you have a very high traffic site.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have little experience about caching. I am working for a research project and the traffic is small. Could you advice on how to determine the duration of cache? In addition, how to instruct the prerender to render the page in case the user has updated it?

Comment: Sure! The duration of the cache is highly dependent on your website, how often the crawlers visit (and revisit) your URLs, and how often your pages might be updated with new information. On Prerender.io, we cache any page that returns a status code 200 and we continue to recache that page to update it with the latest information. That way, we can always serve a cached page if possible. If you are running your own Prerender server and are using a normal in-memory or CDN cache with an expiration, you will need to build your own custom logic to handle clearing cached pages.